# how to properly wait for n seconds

Tags: common-lisp

I want to implement a function which waits n seconds before retrying in case of a failure, but what would be the proper way of implementing the waiting-routine.

I figured that an endless loop with an if-clause might cause unwanted CPU-usage.

```
(do ((time (+ (get-universal-time) (- n 1)))
     (time-cur (get-universal-time) (get-universal-time)))
    ((< time time-cur) nil))
```

Therefore: Would this be considered proper code or is there a more standard way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't [SLEEP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_sleep.htm) what your're looking for?

Comment: Just FYSA, in MCL it seems that sleep is implemented with a process-wait call. Worth a look in the RMCL src if you're curious.